# Как сделать выезжающее горизонтальное меню при клике на гамбургер на чистом javascripte?

Tags: html, css, css3, html5

Как сделать выезжающее горизонтальное меню при клике на гамбургер на чистом javascripte, при адаптации?

Вот код html:

```css
.gamburger {
     width: 40px;
     cursor: pointer;
     display: none;
    }
    
    .gamburger span {
     height: 4px;
     background: #fff;
     margin-bottom: 5px;
     display: block;
    }
```

```html
<nav class="navigation">
       <div class="container">
        <ul class="menu">
         <li class="menu__item"><a href="#" class="menu__link">Home</a></li>
         <li class="menu__item"><a href="#" class="menu__link">About</a></li>
         <li class="menu__item"><a href="#" class="menu__link">Team</a></li>
         <li class="menu__item"><a href="#" class="menu__link">Lessons</a></li>
         <li class="menu__item"><a href="#" class="menu__link">News</a></li>
         <li class="menu__item"><a href="#" class="menu__link">Conracts</a></li>
        </ul>
        <div class="gamburger">
         <span></span>
         <span></span>
         <span></span>
        </div>
       </div>
      </nav>
```

Comment: А где код JS? Или вы подразумеваете чтоб всё выполнили за вас? Попробуйте сделать что-то, а потом напишите с вашим кодом и опишите что не получается и что не можете понять. Вам обязательно помогут

Comment: да и css лучше добавьте, гамбургер же нужно рисовать

Comment: Я просто js пока что не знаю, думал, чтоб кто-нибудь помог написать

Comment: Если вы не знаете пока js, так сделайте это меню на чистом css.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JavaScript код скрытия и показа меню. Для навешивания анимации и прочих эффектов используйте библиотеку Jquery.

```js
var burger = document.querySelector('.gamburger');
var menu = document.querySelector('.menu');

burger.addEventListener('click', function () {

  if (menu.classList.contains('menu-closed')) {
    menu.classList.remove('menu-closed');
    menu.classList.add('menu-opened');
  } else {
    menu.classList.add('menu-closed');
    menu.classList.remove('menu-opened');
  }
});
```

```css
.gamburger {
 cursor: pointer;
}

.menu-opened {
 display: block;
}

.menu-closed {
 display: none;
}
```

```html
<nav class="navigation">
  <div class="container">

    <ul class="menu menu-closed">
      <li class="menu__item">
        <a href="#" class="menu__link">Home</a>
      </li>
      <li class="menu__item">
        <a href="#" class="menu__link">About</a>
      </li>
      <li class="menu__item">
        <a href="#" class="menu__link">Team</a>
      </li>
      <li class="menu__item">
        <a href="#" class="menu__link">Lessons</a>
      </li>
      <li class="menu__item">
        <a href="#" class="menu__link">News</a>
       </li>
      <li class="menu__item">
        <a href="#" class="menu__link">Conracts</a>
      </li>
    </ul>

  <button class="gamburger">иконка гамбургер</button>
  </div>
</nav>
```